# Unable to combine multiple not-regex conditions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to locate documents where field of type string stackTrace exists but contains neither "PROVIDER_SOURCE" nor "providers"

The count seems to make logical sense:

```
db.GroovyScriptResult.find({stackTrace:{$exists: true, $not: /PROVIDER_SOURCE/}}).count();
60
db.GroovyScriptResult.find({stackTrace:{$exists: true, $not: /PROVIDER_SOURCE/, $not: /providers/}}).count();
48
```

But when I print one, the document returned does include a stackTrace which contains "PROVIDER_SOURCE".  What am I doing wrong?

```
db.GroovyScriptResult.findOne({stackTrace:{$exists: true, $not: /PROVIDER_SOURCE/, $not: /providers/}});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532313c8aa3c937c43ca40cb"),
    "stackTrace" : "Exception: could not execute query; SQL [/* criteria query */ select... this_.PROVIDER_SOURCE ..."
}
```

Comment: Not rally that sure what you are saying as none of this is valid syntax. Perhaps show what you are actually doing, even if it is failing?

Comment: The lines that start with 'db' are what I am actually doing, followed by the actual output (stackTrace edited for brevity).  I have accepted Anand's answer suggesting the use of $and, thanks.

Comment: This mongodb university video says that the syntax I originally used should have worked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYk7pjgjjzc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator to achieve what you want:

```js
db.GroovyScriptResult.findOne({
    $and:[
       {stackTrace:{$exists:true}}, 
       {stackTrace:{$not:/PROVIDER_SOURCE/}}, 
       {stackTrace:{$not:/providers/}}
    ]
})
```

Comment: the query operator is so ugly comparing to SQL.